# The vessel and the master

Tags: riddle

```
I invite you, logician,
to explain this addition:

How the female of distinction
of the name in omission (I won't ease you in this commission)
with the feelings in ignition, maybe going for demolition
equals as redefinition
to decreased photoemission
of facial hair's composition.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon the title, I think the answer is

> Blackbeard and his ship Queen Anne's Revenge

Starting with the final two lines, we find

> decreased photoemission -> black
>  facial hair's composition -> beard

which massively helps to explain

> female of distinction -> Queen
>  (named omitted)
>  with the feelings in ignition, maybe going for demolition -> Revenge

so it all holds together.

Comment: Correct. Nice of you to explain your thought sequence as a new user; nice job.